# New to Derby starter app crashing

Tags: coffeescript, derbyjs

I am new to Derby and just installed it on Ubuntu 12.10.

I have the following installed.

- node v0.11.6-pre
- Derby 0.5.9
- Mongo git master
- Redis 2.2.12

I created the starter CoffeeScript application using `derby new --coffee testapp`.  It seems like things installed just fine.

When I try to run the app using `npm start` I get the following error:

```
digilord@digidev:~/testapp$ npm start

> testapp@0.0.0 start /home/digilord/testapp
> ./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee server.coffee

Master pid  12985

/home/digilord/testapp/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/optparse.js:51
        throw new Error("unrecognized option: " + arg);
              ^
Error: unrecognized option: --debug-port=5859
at OptionParser.exports.OptionParser.OptionParser.parse (/home/digilord/testapp/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/optparse.js:51:19)
at parseOptions (/home/digilord/testapp/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:464:29)
at Object.exports.run (/home/digilord/testapp/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:55:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/digilord/testapp/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee:7:41)
at Module._compile (module.js:450:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:468:10)
at Module.load (module.js:350:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:306:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:491:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:813:3
digilord@digidev:~/testapp$
```

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from TheOceanMethod I was able to get everything working.  Thought I was going to stop there huh?

Here's the solution:

- Derby 0.5.9
- Node v0.10.15
- Mongo git master
- Redis 2.6.14

Derby 0.5.9 requires Node to be v0.10.15.  Not Derby specifically.  Some of the dependancies require that version of Node.  Redis needs to be v2.6+, so 2.6.14 works.

One other thing.  In the `server/index` file there is a line that references `../../public` that is commented out.  In order to get the ability to serve images you need to uncomment that line.